# Is there a reason why that Picasso unable to load the images into the last two imageviews?

Tags: java, android, picasso

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploaded_documents);
    frontICImageView = findViewById(R.id.frontImageView);
    backICImageView = findViewById(R.id.backImageView);
    selfieImageView = findViewById(R.id.selfieImageView);
    payslipImageView = findViewById(R.id.payslipImageView);
    String frontICURL = "https://www.example.com/image1.png"
    String backICURL = "https://www.example.com/image2.png"
    String selfieURL = "https://www.example.com/image3.png"
    String payslipURL = "https://www.example.com/image4.png"
    if(frontICURL != null) {
        if(!frontICURL.equals("false")){
            Picasso.get().load(frontICURL).into(frontICImageView);
        }
    }
    if(backICURL != null) {
        if(!backICURL.equals("false")){
            Picasso.get().load(backICURL).into(backICImageView);
        }
    }
    if(selfieURL != null) {
        if(!selfieURL.equals("false")){
            Picasso.get().load(selfieURL).placeholder(R.drawable.not_applicable).into(selfieImageView);
        }
    }
    if(payslipURL != null) {
        if(!payslipURL.equals("false")){
            Picasso.get().load(payslipURL).into(payslipImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Picasso only able to load the images into the first two imageviews whereas the other two imageviews are always blank(white). How can I fix this? Been debugging for hours.

There is permission for Internet and the images works fine in browser.

Comment: swap the url for the one that works for the one that doesn't. That way you know if the problem is in the data, or the image loading.

Comment: the problem is in the image. but just couldn't find out why it cant load images captured from the phone camera! @Blundell

Comment: @Blundell Glide managed to load the images. Not sure whats wrong with Picasso.

Comment: :shrug: if it is any concession we benchmarked imageloaders a few years ago and ended up picking Glide. Sorry it was internal so no link

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your url before you use them with Picasso

```
String payslipURL = "https://www.example.com/image1.png"
String url = Uri.parse(payslipURL)
                .buildUpon()
                .build()
                .toString();
Picasso.get().load(url).into(payslipImageView);
```